# Symfony2 doesn't persist all the columns in a table

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a entity with several fields. Now I have added to my database a new column "date" that is a datetime object.

But when I add a new register to the database this field always have value null, never caught the value that I put in the form.

The entity have the correct values, but if I saw all the values, the entity manager has a variable called "SelectColumnListSQL", and in this SQL action, doesn't appear the field "date".

The logs doesn't write any error, only store in my database the rest of the fields ok but this not.

If hay use dev enviromnent, in this case all works right :S

Any idea??

--- Entity Info ---

```
 /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $date;

 /**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return Quotes
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you clear the cache? why you don't use the dev mode by default?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have cleaned cache, and I need to use the production enviromnent to publish my application on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Please, concrete which ORM are you using (Doctrine, Propel...)

Have you already run the following commands?

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities 
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

You must include the info in your Entity dir in your Bundle

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Doctrine. Yes I use this commands and all is right. Even in dev env all works fine. Now I have added my entity information.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you forget one setter method or the method is misspelled.

See the example below for more details.

Assume that you have this entity

```
class Entity{
    // ...
    private field;


    // the getter and setter methods
    public function getField(){
    // ...
    }

    public function setField(){ // I guess this function is missing or misspelled
    // ...
    // If the function is missing or misspelled, 
    // doctrine will not take into account the changes you did for that field
    }

}
```

best,

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure I have all this fields. I have added this information to my original post. thanks :)

Comment: Give me your entity to see what to propose!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have totaly updated your database by this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but my database is updated, I have used this command :/